# Sum of terms of a geometric sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having a hard time understanding how to find the terms of a geometric sequence. I made an attempt on a problem I had, but if feels wrong. The thing is, I'm not sure where I made a mistake. I'm mostly just mimicking the one example solution there is for my assignment, but the variable for that example isn't a fraction. Here's the problem I'm struggling with:

Evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{99} (-\frac{2}{3})^i$

Here was my attempt:

$S_{n} = 1 + (-\frac{2}{3})^1 + (-\frac{2}{3})^2 + ... + (-\frac{2}{3})^{99} = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{99} (-\frac{2}{3})^i$

$(\frac{2}{3})S_{n} = (\frac{2}{3})^1 + (\frac{2}{3})^2 + ... + (\frac{2}{3})^{99} + (\frac{2}{3})^{100} = $

$\left(\frac{1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{100}}{1 - \left(-\frac{2}{3}\right)}\right) = -\frac{2}{3}^{100}$

Comment: I do not understand your last equality.

Comment: Hint: $(1 - x^n) = (1 - x)(x^{n - 1} + \dots + x + 1)$. Do you see how that equation can be manipulated to give a nice formula for the first $n$ terms of a geometric series?

Comment: Your first equality is also incorrect, since multiplying both sides by $\frac{2}{3}$ gives an alternating sum.

Comment: @user1090793 Thanks for the reply. However, I don't see yet what the next step would be in the example equation you provided.

Comment: @HappyDay Thanks for the reply, however I don't understand it fully. Math is not my strong suit... By "alternating sum" do you mean it would look something like this? = (-2/3)^1 + (2/3)^2 + ... + (-2/3)^99

Comment: I mean $$\frac{2}{3} S=(\frac{2}{3})^1-(\frac{2}{3})^2+(\frac{2}{3})^3-(\frac{2}{3})^4+\dots -(\frac{2}{3})^{100}$$
But, as I mentioned in my answer, I don't see how this is useful if you can immediately use the sum formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are allowed to use the formula for the sum of a geometric sequence, since you attempted using it. You don't need to go through the trouble of multiplying both sided by $\frac{2}{3}$. Instead, you can immediately apply:

$$\sum_{i=N_1}^{N_2} q^i= \frac{q^{N_1}-q^{N_2+1}}{1-q} \quad\quad \text{for all}\space\space q\in\mathbb{R}$$

In your case $q=-\frac{2}{3}$, $N_1=0$, $N_2=99$, so you get

$$\sum_{i=0}^{99} (-\frac{2}{3})^i=\frac{(-\frac{2}{3})^0-(-\frac{2}{3})^{100}}{1-(-\frac{2}{3})}=\frac{1-(\frac{2}{3})^{100}}{\frac{5}{3}}=\frac{3}{5}-\frac{3}{5}\cdot (\frac{2}{3})^{100} \approx 0.5999999999$$

This is very close to the infinite sum result, since $99$ for the number of terms is relatively large.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept the answer if it answers your question:)

Comment: accepted! Though I have a followup question -- in the initial example I was following, the formula is given as:

a(1-r^n/1-r).

However, in your example, the r^n is replaced by q^N2+1. Do you know why there would be a difference of index there?

Comment: Ah, I see it now, thanks!

Comment: Actually, to be more exact, your formula uses $N_1=0$, $N_2=n-1$ (meaning, it sums the first $n$ terms starting at $i=0$). 
The $a_1$ is simply a factor that you can multiply both sides of the formula in my answer by.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clarification.